# ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2.90 3.50 2.35'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping

I'm pulling data from a csv file and need to manipulate the data for analysis.

When I try to convert column (1x2) in DataFrame (Pandas) I get error :

**ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2.90  3.50  2.35'**

Here is the link to my file code:

https://github.com/uncleTech/Bet_Odds/blob/main/Bet_Odds.ipynb

I'll be delighted if you can help!

Thank you.

Comment: ps! I need to convert column (1x2) to 'FLOAT' , currently it reads dtype 'string' re object.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to extract the floats from the string

```
float_list = list(map(float, '2.90 3.50 2.35'.split()))
```

Comment: Yes I want to convert the string to float. ie. turn odds_df column ('1x2') to float number. Did you manage to check the link? Thanks @Jarvis

Comment: There are three floats in `'2.90 3.50 2.35'`, which one do you want? @stephen.m

Comment: I need to work with all three floats. Like divide each float into 1 for example 1/2.90 etc.